# Can an INSERT result in more than one row in a trigger "inserted" table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, triggers

I know that within a trigger - at least for SQL Server - one should never assume that the `inserted` table has just one row, which means SQL like this in a trigger is usually bad:

```
select @UserID = ID from inserted
```

But out of curiosity, can a set of INSERT statements ever result in an `inserted` table of more than one row? I know it's easy enough with an UPDATE, but from my tests I can't simulate a similar result for INSERTs. I've tried sending across sets of inserts before sending the batch terminator, e.g:

```
insert into TriggerTest (col2) select 'a'
insert into TriggerTest (col2) select 'b'
insert into TriggerTest (col2) select 'c'
go
```

And also wrapping them in transactions:

```
begin tran
insert into TriggerTest (col2) select 'a'
insert into TriggerTest (col2) select 'b'
insert into TriggerTest (col2) select 'c'
commit
```

But it will always result in the trigger fired 3 times with an `inserted` table of 1 row, and never one time with an `inserted` table of 3 rows.

That completely makes sense to me (they are 3 separate statements after all), and I don't need to actually do it, I'm just wondering if INSERTS alone can ever behave differently to this.

**Edit:** this is a dumb question: of course it can, when inserting a result set!

```
insert into TriggerTest (col2) select 'a' union select 'b'
```

... or any other sort of set.

Forgive me, it is almost 3AM here. I'll leave this question here for people who should know better anyway.

Comment: Don't work late into the night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
insert into TriggerTest (col2) 
select 'a'
union 
select 'b'
union
select 'c'
```

Comment: Yeah, realised how silly I was immediately after posting the question. Well, free points for you.